# Amazon AWS get object URI

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using following code to get URI but it gives exception:

```
s3.putObject(bucket, fileToPut, file.ref.file)
        val s3Object = s3.getObject(bucket, fileToPut).orNull
        if(s3Object != null){
          val assetUrl = s3Object.getObjectContent.getHttpRequest.getURI
         }
```

[image]

I am unable to get uploaded object URI

Please help

Comment: You should not download the object to get the metadata. The standard aws sdk client provides the metadata as a result of the putObject method. I'm not sure which framework you are using but since it returns and option i guess it is some kind of wrapper. You should provide these information and post the actual exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the url of the object you could use

```
s3Client.getResourceUrl("your-bucket", "path/file.txt");
```